# What's wrong in this code i provided?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>     
#include<math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()    
{        
    int x[100];         
    float a,f,t;

    cout<<" Enter the amplitude:";
    cin>>a;

    cout<<"Enter frequency:";
    cin>>f;

    f=1.0/f;

    cout<<"Enter the time interval::";
    cin>>t;

    int i=0;        
    while(i<t)
    {
        x[i] = a * sin(2 * 3.14 * f * t); 
        cout<<x[i]<<"  ";
    }

    return 0;       
}
```

When I run it, I simply get a huge number of values output, all the same. For example, entering `5`, `7` and `9` gives me the continuous output:

```
4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4  4
:
and so on...
```

Comment: The only thing wrong is that you haven't told us what's wrong. What is the code supposed to do, and what is it actually doing.

Comment: Write a maths formula,I guess for signal processing.

Comment: You need three things. Change x[100] from int to float. Probably t to i ( something like that depending on what you want). Then add i++ as the last line.

Answer (score 2):

You're neither incrementing `i` nor decrementing `t`, meaning that your loop is very likely to be an infinite one:

```
while(i<t)
{
    x[i] = a * sin(2 * 3.14 * f * t); 
    cout<<x[i]<<"  ";
 }
```

Presumably there should be something like an `i++` inside that loop body, depending on your needs.

You'll probably also find that every array element is being set to the same value because you're using `t` in the calculation rather than some function of `i`.

Answer (score -1):

You need to include two headers.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
```

Comment: They're headers rather than libraries, and they were there. It's just that the poor formatting of the code rendered them wrongly so they couldn't be seen.

Comment: Write without thinking. I mean library.